Process to remove High availability and Break the cluster
We have a 4 node High availability group. We now will have to make the primary a standalone server and remove all the replicas and break the cluster.
Before we attempt this on production below is what we have determined

Delete the high availability group
Remove the nodes from the setup.exe and in maintenance have to select remove node.
Remove the roles from Cluster Manager
Destroy the cluster Cluster Manager.

Since we never done this is real life , please advise if there are any additional considerations that needs to me be made or any process that we are missing here.
I appreciate all the input.

Honestly, I'd just pave on of the current servers, load it to what you want, create an availability group over to it as read-scale, then repoint/rename whatever is needed and call it a day. You can then just straight decom the entire cluster and not have to mess with it.

The application will still need to point to the current primary and it an enterprise license.

Yes, until the cut over. You need Enterprise to do your current 4 node Ag so there should be no change there.

If you want to do an edition downgrade, just pave one of the servers, install Standard Edition, and use backup/restore to migrate the database instead of a read-scale AG.
